# Asymptotic growth of the price of anarchy for polynomial latency functions in selfish routing

Tags: asymptotics, algorithmic-game-theory

In Proposition 5.1 in http://timroughgarden.org/papers/indep.pdf the claim is that 
$$
\left(1 - \frac{p}{(p+1)^{\frac{p+1}{p}}}\right) = \Theta\left(\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\right)
$$
but it is never proven. Asking [wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%20-%20p%2F%28%28p%2B1%29%5E%7B%28p%2B1%29%2Fp%7D%29%29%20for%20p%20to%20infinity) it indeed gives this result. It does something with a generalized Puiseux series of which I have never heard. Is there an easy way to obtain this asymptotic behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to take the reciprocal of what is in the large brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Start with
$$A={(p+1)^{\frac{p+1}{p}}}\implies \log(A)={\frac{p+1}{p}}\log(p+1)$$ 
$$\log(A)=\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1+\log \left({p}\right)}{p}+\frac{1}{2
   p^2}-\frac{1}{6 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=p+\left(1+\log \left({p}\right)\right)+\frac{\left(1+\log
   \left({p}\right)\right)^2+1}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$
Continuing the process
$$\left(1 - \frac{p}{(p+1)^{\frac{p+1}{p}}}\right)=\frac{1+\log \left({p}\right)}{p}-\frac{(2+\log
   \left({p}\right)) \log
   \left({p}\right)}{2p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Trying for $p=10$, the exact value is $0.2847$ while the truncated expansion gives $0.2807$

**Edit**

We could do a better approximation using Padé-like approximants to get for the expression
$$\frac{6 p+4}{6 p^2+4 p+3}+\frac{2 p-1 }{2 p^2+p+1}\log (p)-\frac{\log ^2(p)}{2 \left(p^2+p+1\right)}+\frac{\log ^3(p)}{6 p \left(p^2+p+1\right)}$$ which, for $p=10$, would give $0.28483$ while the exact value is $0.28473$

Comment: Aw man - you beat me to it :)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch. For once, the old man has been faster ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what happens starting at the second line?

Comment: @Ruben. This is just Taylor expansion. What is the problem ? Cheers

Comment: I guess my Taylor expansion skills are a bit rusty then ;), at what point?

Comment: @Ruben. Don't repeat it in front of my wife. I felt in love with Taylor series some 62+ years ago and my passion for it increases every single day.